# jQuery dataTables : Clicking thead should sort descending and then ascending for all columns

Tags: sorting, datatable, datatables

I am trying to change the default sorting direction. The default order is ascending and then descending. I am trying to reverse it.

The sorting direction should be independent and should apply to all the columns( Number of columns vary with different tables ) The script I have to initiate datatable is generic.

Sorting should only apply on click.

I found few examples but they are column specific https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/sort_direction_control.html

Here is my script

```js
jQuery(function($) {
   $(".datatable").dataTable({
    "paging": false,
    "searching": false,
    "info": false,
    "orderCellsTop": true
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All options and settings has default values defined in the internal `DataTable.defaults` object. This object is available for altering through `$.fn.dataTable.defaults`. This is poorly documented on the website, but very well documented in the code. Open a none minified jquery.dataTables.js and search for DataTable.defaults.

To reverse the default ordering for *all* columns, so it becomes `desc`, `asc` :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.column.asSorting = ['desc', 'asc'];
```

To set the initial ordering for the first column to desc

```js
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.aaSorting = [[0,'desc']];
```

Likewise you can simply alter the defaults so you not need to set any generic options in your `dataTable()` at all :

```js
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.bPaginate = false;    //paging: false
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.bFilter = false;      //searching: false
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.bInfo = false;        //info: false
$.fn.dataTable.defaults.bSortCellsTop = true; //orderCellsTop: true
```

see demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/f31pncb4/**

Answer (score 2):

You can do it while initializing:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".datatable").dataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "info": false,
        "orderCellsTop": true,
        aoColumnDefs: [
            {
                orderSequence: ["desc", "asc"],
                aTargets: ['_all']
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Richard's answer above works but is the legacy approach.  The syntax for current versions is similar and a bit simpler:

```
var myTable = $('table').DataTable({
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "orderSequence" : [ "desc", "asc" ],
            "targets" : "_all"
        }
    ]
});
```

Slightly off topic but note capital "D" in `DataTable()` which returns an api instance instead of a jquery object.  This is important since doing it this way allows you easier access to the api after initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the @Eaten by a Grue's answer, if we want, we can use the same [orderSequence API](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderSequence) to reverse the sort order using HTML only.

Under the `<thead>`, we can change the `<th>` as follows:

```
<th data-order-sequence='[ "desc", "asc" ]'>Amount</th>
```